# Visual C++ - Kill process using .net

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, process

I want to be kill a process using Visual C++ as easy as the C# way:

```
foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("ComponentEnvironmentServer"))
{
  process.Kill();
  process.WaitForExit();
}
```

I've seen some examples on the net but they're a lot less simpler than above (cross-platform I guess).  I'm very confused about the relationship between MSVC++ and .Net; I thought the whole reason of the .Net platform was to make things simpler? i.e. to be able to transfer the above code to any .Net language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In managed C++ that would be:

```
 foreach (Process* process in Process::GetProcessesByName(S"ComponentEnvironmentServer"))
    {
        process->Kill();
        process->WaitForExit();
    }
```

.NET allows you to use the same libraries whether you write C#, VB.NET or Managed C++.

For native C++ the code is different as you cant access the .NET libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Managed C++'?

Comment: It's called `C++/CLI` not Managed C++.

Comment: To be more precise, Managed C++ is the first, and C++/CLI the redesigned C++ binding for .NET . Both are .NET languages inspired by C++, but the second is much closer to ISO C++. Microsoft has therefore deprecated Managed C++.

Comment: True, sorry for mixing up the terms here. The correct is of course 'C++/CLI'.